# How to push down project, filter, aggregation to TableScan in Calcite

Tags: java, database, apache-calcite

I am using Apache Calcite to implement a distributed OLAP system, which datasource is RDBMS. So I want to push down the project/filter/aggregation in `RelNode` tree to `MyTableScan extends TableScan`. In `MyTableScan`, a `RelBuilder` to get the pushed `RelNode`. At last, `RelBuilder` to generate the Query to the source database. At the same time, the project/filter/aggregation in original `RelNode` tree should be moved or modified.

As I known, Calcite does not support this feature.

> Current limitations: The JDBC adapter currently only pushes down table scan operations; all other processing (filtering, joins, aggregations and so forth) occurs within Calcite. Our goal is to push down as much processing as possible to the source system, translating syntax, data types and built-in functions as we go. If a Calcite query is based on tables from a single JDBC database, in principle the whole query should go to that database. If tables are from multiple JDBC sources, or a mixture of JDBC and non-JDBC, Calcite will use the most efficient distributed query approach that it can.

In my opinion, `RelOptRule` may be a good choice. Unfortunately, when I create new `RelOptRule`, I can not easily find the parent node to remove a node.

`RelOptRule` is a good choice? Anyone has a good idea to implement this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating a new `RelOptRule` is the way to go. Note that you shouldn't be trying directly remove any nodes inside a rule. Instead, you match a subtree that contains the nodes you want to replace (for example, a `Filter` on top of a `TableScan`). And then replace that entire subtree with an equivalent node which pushes down the filter.

This is normally handled by creating a subclass of the relevant operation which conforms to the calling convention of the particular adapter. For example, in the Cassandra adapter, there is a `CassandraFilterRule` which matches a `LogicalFilter` on top of a `CassandraTableScan`. The `convert` function then constructs a `CassandraFilter` instance. The `CassandraFilter` instance sets up the necessary information so that when the query is actually issued, the filter is available.

Browsing some of the code for the Cassandra, MongoDB, or Elasticsearch adapters may be helpful as they are on the simpler side. I would also suggest bringing this to the mailing list as you'll probably get more detailed advice there.

Comment: The `convert` function is what I want, I found it at some rules.

Answer (score 5):

I have create some `RelOptRule` to push down the Project/Filter/Aggregate RelNode upper TableScan. Maybe helpful to others.

`RelOptRule` is used to define some **Rules** to match subtrees in whole RelNode. When match, call the `onMatch` method to do something.

In the `onMatch` method, we can create one new RelNode and call the `transformTo` method to replace the matched subtree.

For example:

```
Project
  |
Filter
  |
TableScan
```

**PushDownFilter** rule as follows:

```
  public class PushDownFilter extends RelOptRule {

  public PushDownFilter(RelOptRuleOperand operand, String description) {
    super(operand, "Push_down_rule:" + description);
  }

  public static final PushDownFilter INSTANCE =
      new PushDownFilter(
          operand(
              Filter.class,
              operand(TableScan.class, none())),
          "filter_tableScan");

  @Override
  public void onMatch(RelOptRuleCall call) {
    LogicalFilter filter = (LogicalFilter) call.rels[0];
    TableScan tableScan = (TableScan) call.rels[1];
    // push down filter
    call.transformTo(tableScan);
  }
}
```

This rule will match the `Filter->TableScan` subtree, then call the `onMatch` method. The method only `transformTo` the `tableScan`. The result is the `Filter->TableScan` replaced by `TableScan`, the whole RelNode as follows:

```
Project
  |
TableScan
```

Note that **the `RelDataType` of new RelNode must be equal to the matched subtree**。

Calcite support some rules to use, for example `FilterJoinRule`, `FilterTableScanRule` and so on.

Comment: we should be providing some extra input information to `call.transformTo(<<here>>)`. It seems the TableScan should be modified in some way to also have the additional filter attributes pushed in, right?